# jQuery countdown for Ruby on Rails datetime input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, jquery-countdown

I am trying to enable a "due date" kind of thing where users pre-select the `datetime` something is due (it can be anything but in my case its the due date for a paper one needs to submit to his/her teacher).

**steps**
Im adding a column to an existing table **pins**

```
$ rails g migration add_due_date_to_pins duedate:datetime
```

**migration**

```
class AddDueDateToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :duedate, :datetime
  end
end
```

In `/app/views/pins/_form.html.erb` I created a form for that input

```
<div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :duedate %>
        <%= f.datetime_select :duedate %>
</div>
```

then in `/app/views/pins/show.html.erb`

```
<%= @pin.duedate %>
```

Right now the time is displayed like such : 2014-08-12 03:01:00 UTC.

Now, I want to use the jquery-countdown-rails gem for the asset pipeline to enable a countdown from the date selected. Something like "**3** days **7** hours and **53** minute left".

I don't know how to extract that date time selected and make it into something that jQuery can manipulate. 
Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a div to attach timer to, so add one to your `/app/views/pins/show.html.erb` file. Second, add some basic javascript to create a Date and start the timer:

```
<div id="due_date_timer"></div>

:javascript
  var year = <%= @pin.duedate.year %>;
  var month = <%= @pin.duedate.month %>;
  var day = <%= @pin.duedate.day %>;

  var date = new Date(year, month, day);
  $("#due_date_timer").countdown({until: date});
```

Comment: where should i include the javascript? currently in my `app/asset/javascript` i have `pins.js.coffee`and `application.js` .

Comment: You can inline it in the show.html.erb file using the `:javascript` block to get started with it. That will create a `<script>` tag with the javascript content.

Comment: Anyway I could organize my code better, put it somewhere in a sort of custom javascript file?

Comment: my pin.js is `coffeescript`. What is the proper syntax in this case? It works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: You should open a new question for how to convert this to a coffeescript function since its veering off-topic for the original question and I can't do it justice in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59147/discussion-between-cyzanfar-and-infused).